# Making text appear while typing - why does this not work in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have a form. On this form there's an input which has javascript attached so that whatever's typed into the input appears in a div elsewhere on the page.

I have two solutions for doing this. One uses keyup and works on all browsers, the other uses onpropertychange (which looks better but doesn't seem to work on Internet Explorer 7 & 8 (works on 9).

Here's the codes:

```
$('#CampaignTitle').keyup(function() {
  $('#titleBar').text(this.value);
});
```

and

```
$('#CampaignTitle').bind("onpropertychange input", function() {
  $('#titleBar').text(this.value);
});
```

How come the 2nd one doesn't work on ie7 and ie8?

Is it something to do with jQuery? I'm new at Javascript

I'm using virtual machines to test the different versions which I've never done before but everything else works so surely it's not that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use only "propertychange" , without the leading "on".

It works in IE9 because IE9 supports the `input`-event

Comment: Thats awesome Dr.Molle, thank you. I do have another small related Qu that it seems stupid to start a new question for - I have a textarea I want to do the same thing for, but when I change the #CampaignTitle and #titleBar bits to the appropriate div id's it doesn't work at all, is there something special I've to do for text areas?

Comment: No, it should work(and work's) the same way with textarea, there must be wrong something else(check if you use the correct id for the textarea)

Comment: thanks, I checked the id and I'm sure it's correct. the text area is a ckeditor - would that be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use `.change()` ?